# Welcome email is not sending for newly registered users though order confirmation email is sending on magento 2 site

Tags: magento2

I have magento 2 site and installed Mageplaza SMTP extension.
Anyway the order confirmation email works fine but not for welcome email for new customers.
Looking forward your kind replies.

It is server on siteground.

welcome email must be sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento doesn't send **New Account** confirmation on email address which is already registered in the Magento admin.